# Can't save Tensorflow custom model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I ran into the problem that I can't save a custom layer in tensorflow.

The code:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(encoder_model, 'encoder1', overwrite=True)
tf.keras.models.save_model(decoder_model, 'decoder', overwrite=True)
```

The error (It's very big so I posted it on Google Drive):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qujHwhZWTHO7zA4dzShGKSbRprqHszLu/view?usp=sharing

The model:

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=False, return_state=True, name='lstm1_enc')
        self.lstm2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm2_enc')
        self.lstm3 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm3_enc')
        
    def call(self, x):
        state = []
        out, h, c = self.lstm3(x)
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm2(out)
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm1(out)
        state.append((h, c))
        
        return state
    
    def get_config(self):
        super().get_config()
        return {
            'lstm1': self.lstm1,
            'lstm2': self.lstm2,
            'lstm3': self.lstm3
        }
    
    
class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.embed = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_len, emb_size, name='embed')
        self.lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm1_dec')
        self.lstm2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 2, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm2_dec')
        self.lstm3 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(h_size * 4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='lstm3_dec')
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_len, activation='softmax', name='fc')
        
    def call(self, x, init_state):
        state = []
        out = self.embed(x)
        out, h, c = self.lstm1(out, initial_state=init_state[2])
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm2(out, initial_state=init_state[1])
        state.append((h, c))
        out, h, c = self.lstm3(out, initial_state=init_state[0])
        state.append((h, c))
        out = self.fc(out)
        
        return out, state

    def get_config(self):
        super().get_config(self)
        return {
            'lstm1': self.lstm1,
            'lstm2': self.lstm2,
            'lstm3': self.lstm3,
            'embed': self.embed,
            'fc': self.fc
        }
    
    
encoder_model = Encoder()
decoder_model = Decoder()

encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, random_vector_len))
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, ))

enc_state = encoder_model(encoder_inputs)
decoder_outputs, _ = decoder_model(decoder_inputs, enc_state)

seq2seq = tf.keras.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

seq2seq.summary()
encoder_model.summary()
decoder_model.summary()
```

For training I combine encoder and decoder into one seq2seq model.

I'm using Tensorflow-gpu v2.5 and python 3.8.

Comment: There's no mentioning of `encoder_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses` in the code. Where is this function?

Comment: @MKimiSH, I'm not defined this function, it's probably somewhere inside TensorFlow.

Comment: This is why you always need to include the full error message verbatim, not individual parts of it.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, corrected it.